# Expanding a div tag from a button click does not work

Tags: html

Below is my code

```
 <div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
                <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>

                    <span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="padding:3px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">More </button>
                        <!--More.<cite title="Source Title">...</cite>-->
                    </span>

                            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                            </div>


                </blockquote>
            </div>
```

When i click on the **More** button it will expand the final **div** section.
But when i have multiple cards its not working. It always expand the very 1st card and non of the other cards are expanding. (card means the last div section).
Is there any way to over come with this thing.

[image]

Comment: do you use the same id on every block? Id has to be unique, so it only get's the first block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Try This Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 80;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "more";
  var lesstext = "less";
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #0254EB
}

a:visited {
  color: #0254EB
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.comment {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
  <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
    <div class="comment more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

  </blockquote>
</div>

<div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
  <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
    <div class="comment more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: This works so fine after doing some adjustments.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The data-toggle selects the first item with #demo because there are multiple. Change the data-collapse and the id of the associated collapsed menu to something unique for the second item

Comment: So lets say if i have 100 cards i have to use 100 unique id's ? Isnt there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: You could write your own JS that's not dependand on IDs

Comment: Hmm..Then thats what im looking for.Can some 1 give me a clue on how to write that.

Answer (score 1):

Your ID's of the element you want to collapse should be unique per card, because the button is referencing `id="demo"` to open/close and should be `id="card-1"` for example and data-target="card-1"

Example"

```
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
      <p>...</p>
      <span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="padding:3px;" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#card1">More </button>
      </span>
      <div id="card1" class="collapse">
        ...
      </div>
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
      <p>...</p>
      <span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="padding:3px;" data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#card2">More </button>
      </span>
      <div id="card2" class="collapse">
        ...
      </div>
    </blockquote>
```

Comment: Yeah this works. :) . I just use unique IDs for my cards. But in the long run this will be bit hard to maintain unique ID's for each card. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to do this. This way you don't have to worry about using unique id's. You can use the following.

HTML:

```html
<div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
  <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
    <span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="padding:3px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">More</button>
  </span>

    <div class="collapse quote-close">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </blockquote>
</div>

<div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150/?random">
  <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
    <span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="padding:3px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">More</button>
  </span>

    <div class="collapse quote-close">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
}

.collapse.quote-close {
  display: none;
}

.collapse.quote-open {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const quote = document.querySelector('.collapse.quote-close');

btn.addEventListener('click', toggleQuote);

function toggleQuote()
{
  if (quote.classList.contains('quote-close'))
  {
    quote.classList.remove('quote-close');
    quote.classList.add('quote-open');
  }
  else {
    quote.classList.remove('quote-open');
    quote.classList.add('quote-close');
  }
}
```

Comment: This was working too but i was thinking below solution would be so nicer.Thanks